# Moving Xcode Project and files to new folder in desktop

Tags: xcode, file

This is a dumb question, but when I try to reorganize my xcode project and move everything to a new folder on my desktop, the project name turns red and is no longer working properly.  How do I move my xcode files to the new folder in my desktop while having it work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem here is maybe not what the user ask for but how to move an xcode project around which has stored internal relative paths outside of the project root (and YES there are valid reasons to do this).

Answer (score 3):

xcode projects are executable.

-close current xcode project

-open project from new location by clicking `.xcodeproj` file

Comment: sorry i should've mentioned that I'm opening my xcode project through my .xcworkspace file not the .xcodeproj file.  It's when I try to open my .xcworkspace file the .xcodeproj file is in red.

Comment: you should move whole directory (.xcworkspace working directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing the current xcode window and then reopening the project from the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the parent folder (with the Xcode closed) should be enough to work, but maybe your project are pointing a library o a file in a different location.

Check on your projects target in the Build Settings tab if there is some path pointing directly to some specific folder/file and modify it